# Limit Ratio of Gamma Functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factorial, gamma-function

How can one prove that for any $x>1$:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^x \Gamma \left(n+1\right)}{\Gamma \left(x+n+1\right)}\right)=1$$

It is easy to show this for $x$ a natural number since we can write the gamma function as a factorial but I would like some ideas on how to prove this for $x$ not a natural number.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Stirling approximation ? With it, you can approximate $\Gamma(y)$ for any $y$ (integer or real).

Comment: I think stirlings approximation could be used

Comment: Then, it is simple ! By the way, **Stirling** or **Stirling's approximation**

Comment: Nice one, thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome ! My pleasure.